# How to convert multi line INI file to single line INI file in Python?

Tags: python, text, ini, converters

I have INI file formatted like this:

[image]

But i need it to look like this:

[image]

What would be the easiest solution to write such converter?
I tried to do it in Python, but it don't work as expected. My code is below.

```
def fix_INI_file(in_INI_filepath, out_INI_filepath):
count_lines = len(open( in_INI_filepath).readlines() )
print("Line count: " + str(count_lines))

in_INI_file = open(in_INI_filepath, 'rt')

out_arr = []
temp_arr = []
line_flag = 0
for i in range(count_lines):
    line = in_INI_file.readline()
    print (i)

    if line == '':
        break

    if (line.startswith("[") and "]" in line)   or   ("REF:" in line)    or   (line == "\n"):
        out_arr.append(line)
    else:
        temp_str = ""
        line2 = ""
        temp_str = line.strip("\n")

        wh_counter = 0
        while 1:             
            wh_counter += 1
            line = in_INI_file.readline()
            if (line.startswith("[") and "]" in line)   or   ("REF:" in line)    or   (line == "\n"):
                line2 += line
                break
            count_lines -= 1
            temp_str += line.strip("\n") + " ; "    
        temp_str += "\n"
        out_arr.append(temp_str)
        out_arr.append(line2 )


out_INI_file = open(out_INI_filepath, 'wt+')  
strr_blob = ""
for strr in out_arr:
    strr_blob += strr
out_INI_file.write(strr_blob)


out_INI_file.close()
in_INI_file.close()
```

Comment: Your example input doesn't seem like a valid .ini file. But if you do have a typical .ini file, your should use Python's built-in parser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html . That will certainly assist in reading the file and will probably simplify the creation of whatever custom output format you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, there's a much easier way to handle this than by parsing the text by hand. The built-in [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module supports keys without values via the [`allow_no_values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#customizing-parser-behaviour) constructor argument.

```
import configparser


read_config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
read_config.read_string('''
[First section]
s1value1
s1value2

[Second section]
s2value1
s2value2
''')

write_config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)

for section_name in read_config.sections():
    write_config[section_name] = {';'.join(read_config[section_name]): None}

with open('/tmp/test.ini', 'w') as outfile:
    write_config.write(outfile)
```

While I don't immediately see a way to use the same `ConfigParser` object for reading and writing (it maintains default values for the original keys), using the second object as a writer should yield what you're looking for.

Output from the above example:

```
[First section]
s1value1;s1value2

[Second section]
s2value1;s2value2
```